# Data Extraction using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is my code to scrape information from the site http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=26. But i am unable to figure out that how to proceed further to get a dataframe having columns Name, Address, Tel, Fax, Email, Website, Contact Person & Nature of business.

```
import requests 
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase
url = "http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=26"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
Data=[]
for i in soup:
    entry=[]
    Names = [soup.find_all('span', attrs ={'style':'font-size: small'})]
```

The output i am getting from the above code is only one listing detail repeating itself throughout  :-

```
[[[[<span style="font-size: small"><a href="#K"><span style="font-size: small;">K</span></a></span>,
    <span style="font-size: small"><span style="font-size: x-small"><strong><strong><strong><strong><a name="A"><span style="font-size: small;">Alphatron Marine Systems Pte Ltd</span></a></strong></strong></strong></strong><span style="font-size: small;"><br/>
    59 S Tuas South Ave 1<br/>
    Ho Lee Industrial Development<br/>
    Singapore 637418<br/>
    Tel: 6863 0335<br/>
    Fax: 6863 3305<br/>
    Email: </span><a href="mailto:mr@alphatronmarinesystems.com"><span style="font-size: small;">mr@alphatronmarinesystems.com</span></a></span></span>]]],
 [[[<span style="font-size: small"><a href="#K"><span style="font-size: small;">K</span></a></span>,
    <span style="font-size: small"><span style="font-size: x-small"><strong><strong><strong><strong><a name="A"><span style="font-size: small;">Alphatron Marine Systems Pte Ltd</span></a></strong></strong></strong></strong><span style="font-size: small;"><br/>
    59 S Tuas South Ave 1<br/>
    Ho Lee Industrial Development<br/>
    Singapore 637418<br/>
    Tel: 6863 0335<br/>
    Fax: 6863 3305<br/>
    Email: </span><a href="mailto:mr@alphatronmarinesystems.com"><span style="font-size: small;">mr@alphatronmarinesystems.com</span></a></span></span>]]],
 [[[<span style="font-size: small"><a href="#K"><span style="font-size: small;">K</span></a></span>,
    <span style="font-size: small"><span style="font-size: x-small"><strong><strong><strong><strong><a name="A"><span style="font-size: small;">Alphatron Marine Systems Pte Ltd</span></a></strong></strong></strong></strong><span style="font-size: small;"><br/>
    59 S Tuas South Ave 1<br/>
    Ho Lee Industrial Development<br/>
    Singapore 637418<br/>
    Tel: 6863 0335<br/>
    Fax: 6863 3305<br/>
    Email: </span><a href="mailto:mr@alphatronmarinesystems.com"><span style="font-size: small;">mr@alphatronmarinesystems.com</span></a></span></span>]]],
```

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on the URL are completely unstructured, so better option is combine BeautifulSoup and `re` module. This example will print only the parsed data on the screen (I don't have `pandas` installed), but adding to dataframe shouldn't be complicated:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=26'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

# get text information from the table:
t = soup.find(text=lambda t: 'Nature of Business:' in t).find_previous('table')
t = t.get_text().split('X  Y  Z')[-1]

# clean the data
all_text = '\n'.join(line for line in map(str.strip, t.splitlines()) if line)
all_text = re.sub(r'^(Major products/services:.*?\n)', r'', all_text, flags=re.M)

# add some missing information:
all_text = re.sub(r'^(Email:.*?\n)(Contact Person:)', r'\1Website: -\n\2', all_text, flags=re.M)

# get the data:
data = []
for name, address, tel, fax, email, www, person, nob in re.findall(r'(.*?)\n(.*?)\nTel\s*:(.*?)(?:\n+|\s+)Fax\s*:(.*?)\nEmail\s*:(.*?)\nWebsite\s*:(.*?)\nContact [Pp]erson\s*:(.*?)\nNature of Business\s*:(.*?)(?:\n|\Z)', all_text, flags=re.S):
    data.append((name, address, tel, fax, email, www, person, nob))

# print the data
from textwrap import shorten
print('{:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}'.format('Name', 'Address', 'Tel', 'Fax', 'Email', 'Website', 'Contact Person', 'Nature of business'))
for row in data:
     print('{:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}'.format(*map(lambda x: shorten(x, 20, placeholder=" >>"), row)))
```

Prints:

```
Name                 Address              Tel                  Fax                  Email                Website              Contact Person       Nature of business  
Alphatron Marine >>  59 S Tuas South >>   6863 0335            6863 3305            >>                   >>                   Mr Maurice Rutten    Electronic & >>     
ASL Shipyard Pte Ltd 19 Pandan Road >>    6264 3833            6266 1473            >>                   www.aslmarine.com    Mr Ang Kok Eng       Shipyard            
Astoria Solutions >> 30 Toh Guan Road >>  6444 2848            6234 4671            >>                   >>                   Mr Dominic Loke      Management >>       
Atwin Marine >>      2 Gul Lane >>        6748 0330            6748 1012            atwin@atwin.com.sg   www.atwin.com.sg     Mr Atwin Fong        Marine >>           
Beng Kuang Marine >> 55 Shipyard Road >>  6266 0010            6264 0010            bkm@bkmgroup.com.sg  www.bkmgroup.com.sg  Ms Irene Lim         Marine >>           
Chugoku Marine >>    22 Tuas Street >>    6861 6500            6861 3002            sam@cmpsin.com.sg    www.cmp.co.jp        Mr Sam Wee           Corrosion Control   
Crestsa Marine & >>  15 Pandan Road >>    6238 8881            6278 2759            >>                   >>                   Mr Lau Boon Hwee     Shipyard, >>        
Damen Shipyards >>   29 Tuas Crescent >>  6861 4180            6861 4181            >>                   www.damen.com        Mr Michel >>         Shipyard            
DDW-PaxOcean >>      33 Tuas Crescent >>  6862 1188            6861 2452/6862 5205  >>                   www.drydocks.sg      Mr Abdul Gahni >>    Shipyard            
Dundee Marine & >>   14 Pioneer Sector >> 6861 1866            6861 1073            >>                   www.dundee.com.sg    Mr Tan Siam Weng     Shipyard            

... and so on.
```

Comment: That's awesome !! it worked for me, Thank you so much Andrej !!!